# How to make notification but no noise when timer goes off?

Tags: iphone, ios

Using the timer in the clock app, how can I make it so that there is a notification and maybe even vibration, but no noise, when the timer goes off? All the options I can see are for audible ringtones. When I change it to "stop playing" there is no notification either.

Comment: You could add your own ringtone (I have a "5 seconds of silence" tone exactly for this).

Comment: @nohillside can I do that using only my phone? I found a guide for adding ringtones to iPhone that uses iTunes on a computer, but i dont have that rn

Comment: Has been a while (and I probably synced from a computer). Support.apple.com might have a document explaining how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This website](https://www.coolmuster.com/idevices/make-a-voice-memo-a-ringtone.html) describes a way to create a ringtone using only your iPhone.

I achieved a silent timer on iOS 15.6 using GarageBand 2.3.12.

1. Download Apple's GarageBand app free of cost.
2. Open the app and scroll through the start screen until you see 'Audio Recorder', open this new project.
3. Use the red record button up top to record for a short moment (stop by pressing the button again), we will make it silent later. Ensure that the recording stays under 40 seconds.
4. Open the [track controls](https://support.apple.com/guide/garageband-iphone/use-the-track-controls-chs175dc411/ios) (icon showing three mixing board sliders in the top left). In the output panel move the track volume slider all the way to the left. When you play your track it should now be completely silent.
5. Export the song using the downwards pointing triangle button on the top left, and choose to export to 'My Songs'. You should now see a Files view, long-press the newly exported "song", tap Share, and choose Ringtone as a format. Export it using the name that you like. Press OK.
6. Go to the Clock app, and in the 'When Timer Ends' menu you should now see your silent recording at the top of the list. When the timer now ends you won't hear any sound, but will still receive a notification and feel the vibration (if enabled).

<sup>If you want to edit your GarageBand ringtones, before you finish step 5 above you can tap on 'Your Ringtones' to delete any you have saved.</sup>